# WebView android - ¿Porqué me redirecciona al navegador?

Tags: java, android, webview-android

Buen día,Tengo un ListView que contiene un webView, que debe cargar una página web, todo normal hasta ahí, pero en vez de que lo cargue en el recuadro del WebView, me salta la opción de "abrir con", algo como esto:

[image: Efecto]

cuando lo que yo quiero, es que el dato lo cargue en el webView, como en un recuadro como este:

[image: Resultado esperado]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldc2n.png)

El código con el que llamo al WebView y le doy la URL es el siguiente:

```
WebView imagen=(WebView)item.findViewById(R.id.WViewImg);
                imagen.loadUrl(datos.get(position).getImagen());
```

**¿Porque pasa esto? ¿qué me falta?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas definir que cliente web usara.
Añade al activity lo siguiente:

```
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: era lo que estaba buscando, gracias!